# Cannot remove Folder View widgets from Plasma5 desktop

Tags: kubuntu, 18.04, kde5, plasma-5, widgets

I have added some Folder View widgets in Kubuntu 18.04 but I cannot remove them now.

[image]

Even, after asking [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054204/how-to-uninstall-pre-installed-widgets-in-plasma-5) question on how to uninstall the widget completely from the system, and therefore adding another two to illustrate that question, now I have four such widgets on the desktop.

Removing them and restarting Plasma: they are all back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.

The most acceptable way is to edit the file `/~.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc` and remove some if not all parts that refer to "folder". I have deleted all parts that included the word "folder", and it seems that the problem was fixed. The only customization that I wanted but was lost/reset in this way was the wallpaper - and the panel height.

That file can be removed completely but its removal would reset all the Plasma desktop settings.

(Removing or renaming the folder /usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.folder removes completely this buggy plasmoid, but leaves me with no wallpaper and no mouse actions on the desktop, so that is **not** a solution.)